# Run jQuery on appended content and ajax content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

How do you run jQuery on content loaded in via `append` or AJAX? I've tried `.live` and `.on` but nothing I do seems to work, and most stuff I find is for the removed `.live`.

I'm trying to do a live search, but I have it for inputs and you can add as many of these inputs on a page as you like.

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// ================================ live material search ============================ //

var obj;

//$('input[rel="m-live"]').focus(function(){

$('input[rel="m-live"]').on('focus',function(){

    if($(this).attr('name') == obj){} else { $('#live-search-result').html(""); }
    obj = $(this).attr('name');

    //if($(this).val !== null){ str = "t=s&v=" + $(this).val(); ajax(str); }

    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        height = $(this).height() + 10;

    offset.top = offset.top + height;

    $('#live-search-result').show();
    $('#live-search-result').css({"left":offset.left ,"top":offset.top})

});

$('input[rel="m-live"]').focusout(function(){
    $('#live-search-result').hide();
});

$('input[rel="m-live"]').keyup(function(){
    var str = "t=s&v=" + $(this).val();
    ajax(str);
});

function ajax (str) {
  $.ajax({
        url: '/esystem/pages/ajax/material.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: str,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#live-search-result').html(data);
        }
    });
}

});
```

The append code:

```
function Add(){
$('#material-list').append("<div class='material'><div class='input'>" + 
    "<input type='text' rel='m-live' name='mat-"+curMat+"' placeholder='Material' />" +
    "<div class='logo'><i class='icon-inbox'></i></div></div> <div class='input'>" + 
    "<input type='text' rel='m-price' name='mat-p-"+curMat+"' placeholder='price 0.00' />" +
    "<div class='logo'><i class='smaller icon-gbp'></i></div></div></div>"
);
}

function Remove(){
$('#material-list .material:last-child').remove();
}
```

I've got `.on` in there but does not work on appended inputs.

Side note: What's the default value for an blank input? As you can see in the code I was trying to run the AJAX again if the input was not blank on focus, but it runs whatever.

And then I want to be able to run jQuery on the live search box with ajaxed content to auto fill Name and Price on click.

### PHP code

```
<?php

include '../../core/php/config.php';

$n = $_POST['v'];
$t = $_POST['t'];

if(!empty($n) && $t == "s"){

    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM _materials WHERE name LIKE '$n'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM _materials";

    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){
        if (strpos($row['name'], $n) !== FALSE){
            echo $row['name'] .' - £'. $row['price'] . '<br />';
        }
        else{
            //echo "not found";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: In very short - u need to add `eventListeners` in callback function at the `Add()` func...

Comment: were you attaching the `.on` to the element being added?

Comment: Please be more specific. Check, where you expect to be an error. Does the function in question execute anyway? Place an alert() inside and update your question.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes i was orginally.      

SteAp - Nothing happens atall, And i just tried $('#material-list').on('focus','input[rel="m-live"]',test(this)); And still nothing happens.

Comment: See answer below, `.on` needs to be attached to a non-changing parent, or `document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get events to fire on elements that have been added to the DOM you need to either set the bind after the elements have been added to the DOM, or using `.on` like below

```
$(document).on('click','#SomeButtonID',function(e) {
   alert("i have been clicked");
});

$("body").append('<button id="SomeButtonID">Click Me</button>');
```